# programmatically assign progressbar style Android

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm generating scrollbars programmatically and I have defined a style to change the color, so my question is naturally: How set the scrollbar style of my scrollbars?

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleHorizontal);
// I tried ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, Android.Resource.Drawable.myprogressbar); but it doesn't work
    progressBar.Progress = 25;
    linearLayout.AddView(progressBar);
```

The path of my style is `android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal` so how can I make this?

The XML code (that MUST be made programmatically) is:

```
<ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/myprogressbar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        android:progress="50"
        android:startColor="#ffffff"
        android:endColor="#ff1997e1" />
```

**EDIT:**

I put:

```
ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, Resource.Drawable.myprogressbar);
```

but now no bar is appearing on the app :-(

**EDIT:**

I've test that code too, and nothing appears again :

```
var progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, Resource.Drawable.myprogressbar)
                {
                    Progress = 25,
                    LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent),
                };                
                linearLayout.AddView(progressBar);
```

And when I try to set the progressdrawable after the progressbar creation by using:

```
progressBar.ProgressDrawable = Resource.Drawable.myprogressbar;
```

I have:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to
>   'Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable'. An explicit conversion exists
>   (are you missing a cast?)

**Final edit:**

Here's my last code:

```
// progressbar with custom style (Resources/Drawable/myprogress.xml)
                    ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleHorizontal)
                    {LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)};
                    progressBar.ProgressDrawable = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.myprogressbar);
                    // Compute for the percent of this usage (to assign it to the progressbar)
             progressBar.Progress = 33;
                    linearLayout.AddView(progressBar);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `ProgressBar` is not shown because you forgot to set the `LayoutParameters`. The following code works for me. I tried with various `ProgressBar` styles.

```
var myLinearLayout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.myLinearLayout);

var progressBar = new ProgressBar(this, null, Android.Resource.Attribute.ProgressBarStyleLarge)
    {
        Progress = 25,
        LayoutParameters =
            new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent)
    };

myLinearLayout.AddView(progressBar);
```

**EDIT:**
To pass your own `Drawable`to `progressBar.ProgressDrawable` you need to load it first, just like the error you get indicates.

```
progressBar.ProgressDrawable = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.myprogressbar);
```

Comment: @Cheesnaron : your code maked me traditional progressbar but the idea is to use my custom progressbar made (wich works in xml)